# jQuery Validate displays no message

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

So I have a file upload element on my site:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <textarea id="input-box" placeholder="What's on your mind?" maxlength="10000" name="quick-post-area" class="col-xs-12"></textarea>
    <!-- images -->
    <fieldset class="images">
    <label for="images">Upload an image</label>
    <input type="file" name="image-uploader" id="img-upload" size="50">
    </fieldset>
    <!-- images end -->
<input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="quick-post-submit">
</form>
```

And am trying to validate uploads to check file size with the jQuery validate plugin:

```
$('#img-upload').validate({ rules: { image-uploader: { required: true, extension: "png|jpe?g|gif", filesize: 1048576 }}, messages: { image-uploader: "File must be JPG, GIF or PNG, less than 1MB" } });
```

However when uploading a file that breaks the size limit or even the extension rules, no message is displayed.

Can anyone see anything wrong with my code?

Comment: `inputimage` - You are not adding it to the HTML Element. **Period**.

Comment: @PraveenKumar mistyped it. Question updated - where should the error appear exactly? and would a change trigger event be required for the function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try by giving your the actual form an Id and hook that to the plugin.

So this `<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Becomes this `<form method="post" action="" id="#myId" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Then js becomes this

```
$('myId').validate({ rules: { image-uploader: { required: true, extension: "png|jpe?g|gif", filesize: 1048576 }}, messages: { image-uploader: "File must be JPG, GIF or PNG, less than 1MB" } });
```

Hope this helps.